# How to detect Basic authentication as fall back auth method - Exchange 2016 on prem + Azure MFA

Tags: exchange-2016, azure-mfa

we have configured Azure MFA in our Exchange on-prem 2016. Unfortunately, the MFA control can easily bypass by using an old email client (Outlook 2010 for example). This is a known issue and the upgrade is the natural path. until we walk that path, I wondered if it would be a way to detect those basic authentication attempts.

many thanks

Comment: Can you find the attempts in Azure AD sign-in log?

Comment: the authentiacation happens locally in the server, no web popup appears. I found some logs in the exchange path E:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Mapi. I am trying to index it now in Splunk

Answer (score 0):

I finally used Splunk for it indexing the WinHttp Exchange logs. I had to create the sourcetype for that log files located in [Exchange installation drive]:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\Logging\HttpProxy\Mapi.

> index=msexchange sourcetype=MSExchange:2016:WinHttp host=XXXXXXXX
> AuthMethod=Bearer  | stats count(_time) as
> totalConnections,earliest(_time) as lastcon,values(UserAgent) as
> UserAgents by UserSID | eval last_connection = strftime(lastcon,
> "%Y%m%d") | table UserSID,last_connection, UserAgents,
> totalConnections